# mod_rewrite additional query string - correct syntax

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have a fairly standard mod_rewrite that comes packaged with a CMS called Modx and FURL's are working fine.

It will rewrite

- http://www.domain.co.uk/page to http://www.domain.co.uk/index.php?q=***page_id***

It is configures as below.

```
# Friendly URLs Part
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# Force all pages to go to www.domain.co.uk for SEO
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/dev/$1 [R=301,L]
# Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dev/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I want to add an additional condition that will rewrite an additional query string:

- http://www.domain.com/dev/company/***company_id***
- to http://www.domain.com/dev/index.php?q=***page_id***&company_id=***company_id***

Note *company_id* and *company_id* should be numbers in the actual rewrite.

Have tried a number of iterations but still can not get success.

Help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Friendly URLs Part
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .

# Force all pages to go to www.domain.co.uk for SEO
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/dev/$1 [R=301,L]
#are your sure the above rule shouldn't be :
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ dev/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

#company url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(company)/([^/]+)$ dev/index.php?q=$1&companyid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Gerben - thanks for the answer but unfortunately it doesn't / I can't get it to work still.  I have copied your code but when I examine the server vars via php it returns "REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING = q=company/***id_here***" which to me implies that it is not translating the final "/***id_here***" to be &companyid=***id_here*** where ***id_here*** is the actual integer id obviously - Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING contains the original url. `$_GET['companyid']` should contain the id.

Comment: Gerben thanks for your help. Using $_GET['companyid'] didn't work.  I moved the 'company URL' block above the 'Friendly URL' block and it does now work BUT the final url is like domain.com/dev/company/?company_id=1  I was hoping for no traditional query string so domain.com/dev/company/1 - I think it fires both rules which is why the last query string re-appears but I thought using [L] enforced that to be the last rule run - any ideas? Thanks

Comment: 38 days later! Are you serious?

Comment: Been abroad with work - life has been on hold...but yes still very very serious!  Thanks for your help so far anyhow.

Comment: Fair enough. `domain.com/dev/company/?company_id=1` will not match the rule, because it start with `/dev` not `/company`. What happens when you try `domain.com/company/1`, so without the /dev. Are the rule exactly the way I posted them above, or did you change anything (besides the order)? The fact that the order matters in your case makes me assume you did.

Comment: Gerben - +1 for being the only person that answered!  Also it would appear that the issues I was having were related to the version of Modx (my cms) I was running.  For prosperity and if anyone else stumbles across this I upgraded from 2.2.0 to 2.2.2 and the re-writes started working.